# Is this function composition "legal"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions

I have a question regarding the commutativity of function composition. Here are two examples:

**First example:**
\begin{align}
f_1&: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R,
&f_1(u,v)=u^2-v\sin u 
\tag 1 \\
g_1&: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2,
&g_1(x,y)=(x+y,xe^y) 
\tag 2
\end{align}

And the composition $h_1 = f_1 \circ g_1 :\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ is
\begin{align}
h_1(x,y)&=(f_1\circ g_1)(x,y) \\
&=f_1(g_1(x,y))\\
&= f_1(x+y,xe^y)\\
&=(x+y)^2-xe^y\sin (x+y) \tag 3
\end{align}
*Question: is it possible to compose $g_1\circ f_1$?*

My first thought was "no", according to the definition:

> \begin{align}
> f&: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^p\\
> g&:\mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^n\\
> h&=f\circ g: \mathbb R^m \to \mathbb R^p
> \end{align}
> I.e. $h(x)=(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$

*However, is it not possible to introduce a new function $F_1$ with the right co-domain and compose it with $g_1$, i.e. $g_1 \circ F_1$?*

*Attempt:*
Introduce
\begin{align}
F_1&:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2 \tag 4\\
F_1&(u,v)=(u,f_1(u,v))=(u,u^2-v\sin u) \tag 5
\end{align}
And with $g_1:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ we have the composition
$$
h_2= g_1\circ F_1:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 \tag 6
$$
*According to the definition the composition is valid, however is this "legal"?*
\begin{align}
h_2(u,v)&=(g_1\circ F_1)(u,v)=g(F_1(u,v))\\
&=g(u,u^2-v\sin u)\\
&=(u+u^2-v\sin u,ue^{u^2-v\sin u}) \tag 7
\end{align}

**Second example:**
\begin{align}
f_2&:\mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^2,  &f_2(u,v, w)=(u^3-v\sin u, uvw) \tag 8\\
g_2&:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2,  &g_2(x,y)=ax^2+by \tag 9
\end{align}
$f_2\circ g_2$ is not a valid composition. Now introduce $G_2:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^3$,
$$
G_2(x,y)=(x,y,g_2(x,y))=(x,y,ax^2+by) \tag{10}
$$
So the composition $h_3= f_2\circ G_2:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is
\begin{align}
h_3(x,y)&=(f_2\circ G_2) (x,y)=f(G_2(x,y))\\
&=f(x,y,ax^2+by)\\
&= (x-y\sin x, xy(ax^2+by)) \tag{11}
\end{align}

*Is this legal?*

Comment: It is not a matter of "legality", it is a matter of meaning and usefulness. What is the purpose of "forcing" such a composition ?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a canonical embedding $\mathbb R \subset \mathbb R^2$. So it is not well-defined, without further annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most general definition of composition of functions:

> Let $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ be any non-empty sets, and let $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ and $g \colon Y \rightarrow Z$ be any functions. Then the *composite* function $g \circ f \colon X \rightarrow Z$ is defined as follows:
> $$
> \big( g \circ f)(x) \colon= g\big( f(x) \big) \qquad \mbox{ for all } x \in X.
> $$

Note that in order for the composite function $g \circ f$ to be defined, we must have
$$
\mbox{Range } f \subset \mbox{Domain } g,
$$
where $\mbox{Range } f$ is defined as follows:
$$
\mbox{Range } f \colon= \big\{ \, f(x) \, \colon \, x \in X \, \big\}. 
$$

So in order for the composite $f \circ g$ to be defined, we must also have
$$
\mbox{Range } g \subset \mbox{Domain } f,
$$

Hope this helps.